# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.state.data)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**The error occurs when I try to close the modal window. on the "Close" button. The error says that** _this.state.data [imageKey] .urls' is not an object, but I pass the string.

I am receiving JSON from a custom API endpoint. I was able to iterate over the JSON and output some data, but the problem is with the string reference to the image. I am getting the error:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Dimensions,
  Modal,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';
import ImageElement from './component/ImageElement';
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modalVisible: false,
      data: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=cf49c08b444ff4cb9e4d126b7e9f7513ba1ee58de7906e4360afc1a33d1bf4c0')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          data: data,
        });
      });
  }

  // getImage() {
  //   return this.state.modalImage
  // }

  setModalVisible = (visible, imageKey) => {
    this.setState({ modalImage: this.state.data[imageKey].urls.raw });
    this.setState({ modalVisible: visible });
  };

  render() {
    let images = this.state.data.map((val, key) => {
      return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
          key={key}
          onPress={() => {
            this.setModalVisible(true, key);
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.imagewrap}>
            <ImageElement
              author={{ url: val.user.profile_image.small }} // фото автора
              imgsource={{ url: val.urls.small }} // работа автора
              authorNameProp={val.user.name} // имя автора
            ></ImageElement>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      );
    });
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Modal
            style={styles.modal}
            animationType={'fade'}
            transparent={true}
            visible={this.state.modalVisible}
            onRequestClose={() => {}}
          >
            <View style={styles.modal}>
              <Text
                style={styles.text}
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setModalVisible(false);
                }}
              >
                Close
              </Text>
              <ImageElement imgsource={{ url: this.state.modalImage }}></ImageElement>
            </View>
          </Modal>
          {images}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    overflow: 'scroll',
  },
  imagewrap: {
    margin: 5,
    padding: 2,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height / 2 - 60,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2 - 10,
  },
  modal: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.9)',
  },
  text: {
    color: '#fff',
    zIndex: 20,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 50,
    right: 30,
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  user: {
    color: '#fff',
    zIndex: 20,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 20,
    left: 10,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ImageGallery', () => ImageGallery);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

Seems you missed passing an index in your close handler `this.setModalVisible(false)`, `imageKey` is undefined, and thus `this.state.data[undefined]` is undefined and throws error when you access deeper into the nested properties.

## Solution

Conditionally access the data value based on the `visible` value. Clear out the `modalImage` state when closing the modal.

```
setModalVisible = (visible, imageKey) => {
  this.setState({
    modalImage: visible ? this.state.data[imageKey].urls.raw : null,
    modalVisible: visible,
  });
}
```

Alternatively you can just use [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to do null checks for you.

```
setModalVisible = (visible, imageKey) => {
  this.setState({
    modalImage: this.state.data[imageKey]?.urls?.raw,
    modalVisible: visible,
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
In my case when clicking on 'close' I called the method again. And it was necessary to clear 'modalImage'. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @ОрестЛенцик Yes, exactly. Well, I guess only you can answer if it is necessary to clear, but that seemed a safe assumption on my part from the limited context. The issue is that when you close the modal that the image key isn't defined, so the same logic to set the modal image fails, it's necessary for your code to gracefully handle that.